# Keeping two distant programs in-sync using MySql

Tags: php, c++, mysql, client-server

I am trying to write a client-server app.

Basically, there is a Master program that needs to maintain a MySQL database that keeps track of the processing done on the server-side,

and a Slave program that queries the database to see what to do for keeping in sync with the Master. There can be many slaves at the same time.

All the programs must be able to run from anywhere in the world.

For now, I have tried setting up a MySQL database on a shared hosting server as where the DB is hosted

and made C++ programs for the master and slave that use CURL library to make request to a php file (ex.: www.myserver.com/check.php) located on my hosting server.

The master program calls the URL every second and some PHP code is executed to keep the database up to date. I did a test with a single slave program that calls the URL every second also and execute PHP code that queries the database.

With that setup however, my web hoster suspended my account and told me that I was 'using too much CPU resources' and I that would need to use a dedicated server (200$ per month rather than 10$) from their analysis of the CPU resources that were needed. And that was with one Master and only one Slave, so no more than 5-6 MySql queries per second. What would it be with 10 slaves then..?

Am I missing something?
Would there be a better setup than what I was planning to use in order to achieve the syncing mechanism that I need between two and more far apart programs?

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like you're talking about database as IPC.  I'd look into some other approach if you can.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database-as-IPC

Comment: This is economies of scale in action. Polling every one second seems overly excessive for any web based application. I would consider reducing my polling from 60 / min to 3/min or every 20 seconds. Any jobs that need propogating out to the mySQL server would wait suspended in a job queue.

Comment: @ibiza I would think because they have their own dedicated SQL servers. Any hosted provider would not allow you such intensive useage without cost.

Comment: Shop around and find the best deal. Bear in mind that you can get access to a bare metal server / VM from providers that allow you to host and manage your SQL server. This can be a much cheaper option with CPU and RAM limitations set by the hardware rather than the 'soft' limits set by managed hosting providers. If this is for personal use, host the SQL server locally.

Comment: @DavidBarker: would you mind expanding your last point a bit in an answer please? I am not sure what to take from it...dedicated server = expensive, what would you mean by much cheaper?

Comment: No need for an answer (as I'm not really answering your question per se). Dedicated servers ARE expensive if you look at them from a consumers perspective. However, you've been presented with a problem where the solution is to increase CPU, RAM and HDD. Your options (!localy hosted) all include an investment. Your hosting provider will quote you high numbers as they don't want the traffic. In essence find a provider that will charge you on the value of the product you need rather than charging you for the potential burden on their network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/appengine/) for storing the data. You can read about free quotas and pricing [here](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/appengine/docs/quotas.html).

Comment: Hey, that looks very promising, I definitely need to have a look at that. I'd finally have the need to learn some Python...

Comment: It has a Java API too. And another for the Go language.

Comment: I think I'll change my initial plan and try that new option...I'll learn something new along the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the syncing approach you are taking is probably fine.

The more significant question you need to ask yourself is, **what is the maximum acceptable time between sync's that is acceptable?** If you truly need to have *virtually realtime syncing* happening between two databases on opposite sites of the world, then you will be using **significant bandwidth** and you will unfortunately have to **pay for it**, as your host pointed out.

Figure out what is acceptable to you in terms of time. Is it okay for the databases to only sync once a minute? Once every 5 minutes?

Also, when running sync's like this in rapid succession, it is important to make sure you are not overlapping your syncs: Before a sync happens, test to see if a sync is already in process and has not finished yet. If a sync is still happening, then don't start another. If there is not a sync happening, then do one. This will prevent a lot of unnecessary overhead and sync's happening on top of eachother.

Comment: Hi, I don't need 'real-time' syncing (as in real-time applications), but an update frequency of once per second is a target delay that I would like to achieve.

Comment: just for precision, it's not 2 databases that need syncing, it's 2 programs using the same database

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a shared web host? What you are doing sounds like excessive use for a shared (cPanel-type) host - use a VPS instead. You can get an unmanaged VPS with 512M for 10-20USD pcm depending on spec.

Edit: if your bottleneck is CPU rather than bandwidth, have you tried bundling up updates inside a transaction? Let us say you are getting 10 updates per second, and you decide you are happy with a propagation delay of 2 seconds. Rather than opening a connection and a transaction for 20 statements, bundle them together in a single transaction that executes every two seconds. That would substantially reduce your CPU usage.

Comment: I think an example would be premature without seeing your code first, since there is a high chance I supply code that was not appropriate to your use case. But at the very least your repeated calling a URL will open a fresh database connection on each occasion - this should be kept open. You could run a background task that does your updates on a single connection - that would reduce your CPU usage too.

Comment: What engine are you using with MySQL? Could you use InnoDB, so transactions would be possible? As I understand it, if you open a transaction, issue several updates and then commit, this is faster than the total time to do those updates in auto-commit mode. Some experimentation would probably be useful here.

Comment: I like where this is going, there are certainly optimizations I can do regarding sql queries by using transactions. I will start looking but if you come up with other suggestions or examples, they will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Add some code to your post, and then someone (or me) will tweak it for you. We'd be writing "blind" otherwise, which is less likely to help you. Don't forget the VPS issue as well - a cheap VPS will easily write many more updates per sec than you are presently doing.